# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore not so ubiquitous?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am trying to store key-values with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore. They seem to store fine while the app is installed, but if I delete the app off the device and run the app again, the key-values seem to be lost. Is this expected behaviour, or perhaps is there something I'm missing?

I am storing and retrieving values like so:

```
-(void)setString:(NSString*)stringValue forKey:(NSString*)keyValue {
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    [iCloudStore setString:stringValue forKey:keyValue];
    [iCloudStore synchronize];
}
-(NSString*)getStringForKey:(NSString*)keyValue {
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    return [iCloudStore stringForKey:keyValue];
}
```

What I've already checked:

1. I have enabled iCloud and key-value storage in Target Capabilities.
2. iCloud Drive is enabled on my device and the app itself is enabled.
3. I have waited for some time before trying to load the values to be sure it wasn't just a syncing problem.
4. I have registered an observer in the NSNotificationCentre as per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH7-SW1) for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification. My observer is never called, on first run after install, or subsequent runs. My code(stripped back from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH7-SW1))

   ```
   NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore* store = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(updateKVStoreItems:)                                                         name:NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
                                          object:store];
   [store synchronize];

   - (void)updateKVStoreItems:(NSNotification*)notification {
       NSLog(@"RECEIVED DATA");
   }
   ```

Additional questions -

1. Is there a way of telling when your data has synced *to* the cloud?(i.e. uploaded data)
2. Or the reverse, is there a way of telling when your app has synced successfully *from* the cloud?(i.e. downloaded data) I would have hoped that [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification) would notify for this, but since I'm not receiving this notification, I suspect it's just for when another device has updated the data while the app is open, a suspicion that seems to be confirmed by [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Change_Reason_Values):

> NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange - A value changed in iCloud. This occurs when another device, running another instance of your app and attached to the same iCloud account, uploads a new value."

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable iCloud in the Application Services for the app id in the Apple Developer Portal? After that you also have to create a provisioning profile for the app.

The only difference I see in my code is the "name:" parameter. You need to specify that you want to observe NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver: self
 selector: @selector (storeDidChange:)
 name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification
 object: [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]];
```

Your code throws a warning in my environment

`Instance method '-addObserver:selector:object:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

I also have been using setObject:forKey: instead of setString:forKey:

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comment. Actually the name property is in my question, for some weird formatting reason it's way off on the right side.

I have provisioning profile set to automatic, which means when I enabled iCloud and key-value storage in Target Capabilities, Xcode automatically registered these servers for the team provisioning profile. (I've double checked this in the member centre)